# NTLM Authentication invalid character

Tags: linux, http, authentication, ntlm

I have a problem. When I try to access on my web application I have this error

> Response header 'WWW-Authenticate' value of 'NTLM TlRMTVNTUAACAAAAAAAAACgAAAABggAAAAICAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==\n' contains invalid characters, aborting request

I read about the NTLM Authentication and how it works but I don't understand why there is the special character \n in the response and how I can fix it.

Anyone has the same problem?

**RESOLVED**

```
byte[] msg1 = { (byte) 'N', (byte) 'T', (byte) 'L',
                        (byte) 'M', (byte) 'S', (byte) 'S', (byte) 'P', z,
                        (byte) 2, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, (byte) 40, z, z, z,
                        (byte) 1, (byte) 130, z, z, z, (byte) 2, (byte) 2,
                        (byte) 2, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z };
                res.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "NTLM "
                        + new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encodeBuffer(msg1).trim());
                res.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
```

In this case I added the trim() function and that s work for me!!

Answer (score 0):

**RESOLVED**

```
byte[] msg1 = { (byte) 'N', (byte) 'T', (byte) 'L',
                        (byte) 'M', (byte) 'S', (byte) 'S', (byte) 'P', z,
                        (byte) 2, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, (byte) 40, z, z, z,
                        (byte) 1, (byte) 130, z, z, z, (byte) 2, (byte) 2,
                        (byte) 2, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z };
                res.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "NTLM "
                        + new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encodeBuffer(msg1).trim());
                res.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
```

In this case I added the trim() function and that s work for me!! – travis_91

Comment: I'm trying to resolve a 401 response in my C# web requests. Can you point me to any examples which show the full request/response conversation to handle NTLM authentication from C#? I am trying to access a web page from a SharePoint server. I use the SharePoint CSOM library for accessing sites, list, etc., but to resolve a doc ID URL, I need to handle things manually.

Comment: @Steve - You should direct your question (at)travis_91.